# How to subtract lists constructed same length vectors

Tags: r, list

I simplified as follows:

```
 list( 
      v = c(11,12,13),
      vv= c(21,22,23)
        ) 

 -list(W = c(1,2,3),
       WW= c(1,2,3)
       )
```

MY desired out put is

```
list(c(10,10,10),c(20,20,20))
```

My idea is `for` sentence or `unlist()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you could use `Map`:

```
Map(`-`, l1, l2)
# $v
# [1] 10 10 10
#
# $vv
# [1] 20 20 20
```

where

```
l1 <- list(v = c(11, 12, 13), vv = c(21, 22, 23)) 
l2 <- list(v = c(1, 2, 3), vv = c(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: @CamfordOxbridge, you may use `l2 <- split(c(1:3, 1:3), rep(seq_along(l1), lengths(l1)))`

Comment: Thank you and it goes well !! very thank you. It helps me and please let me use your code in my package.

Comment: Oh!! Sorry, I delete my comment but @Julius Vaninora answered for deleted comments, so I again write. Sorry and Thank you for @Julius. ::::::::::Thank you for rapid reply and I wii try. but to tell the truth, I simplified in above questions and my  actual problem is one list in above is not listed, i.e., `lisl(w=c(1,2,3),ww=c(1,2,3))` is a vector `c(1,2,3,1,2,3)`. So If you know some methods to convert a  vector `c(1,2,3,1,2,3)` to a list `lisl(w=c(1,2,3),ww=c(1,2,3))` then please let me know.